# Gatsby TypeError: createNodeId is not a function

Tags: gatsby

I'm having an issue when trying to create a node ID. The issue is in my gatsby-node.js file... The error is coming from exports.sourceNodes in which the error reads:

```
createNodeId is not a function

TypeError: createNodeId is not a function

gatsby-node.js:32
/home/jorge/Desktop/gatsby_practice/jorge-blog/gatsby-node.js:32:15

Array.forEach

gatsby-node.js:27 Object.exports.sourceNodes
/home/jorge/Desktop/gatsby_practice/jorge-blog/gatsby-node.js:27:11

task_queues.js:95 processTicksAndRejections
internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5
```

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
exports.sourceNodes = async (actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest) => {
const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
const posts = res.data

posts.forEach(post => {
    const node = {
      title: post.title,
      body: post.body,
      id: createNodeId(`Post-${post?.id}`),
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: "Post",
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(post),
        content: JSON.stringify(post)
      }
    }

    actions.createNode(node)
})
}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-moon-okbf6?file=/src/styles/global.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument is an object so you need to destructure it to get at its values. In other words add some curlies "{}".

```
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
```

Link to docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#sourceNodes